# Generic service in Generic Base Controller

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, repository-pattern

I order to avoid DRY I ventured into the idea of generating a generic base class for all my controllers. Everything was fine until the moment of insert a service class. My basecontroller is:

**basecontroller.cs**

```
public class BaseController<TEntity, Tdto, TKey> : Controller
{
    protected TavoraContext _context;
    protected IMapper _mapper;

    private IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, Tdto> _srv;

    public BaseController(IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, Tdto> srv)
    {
        _srv = srv;
    }
```

Then, in one of the controllers:

**companiescontroller.cs**

```
public class CompaniesController : BaseController<Company, CompanySimpleDTO, long>
{

    public CompaniesController(TavoraContext context, IMapper mapper, CompaniesService companiesService) : base(companiesService)
    {
    }
```

CompaniesService inherit from GenericService, that implements IGeneric so, in my opinion there should be no mistake and I getting 'It's not possible to convert from CompaniesService to IGeneric'

**companiesservice.cs**

```
public class CompaniesService : GenericService<Company, long, CompanyDTO>
{

    public CompaniesService(TavoraContext context, IMapper mapper)  : base(context, mapper)
    {

        _runner = new RunnerWriteDb<CompanyDTO, Company>(
            new WriteCompanyAction(
                new WriteCompanyDBAccess(context), mapper), context);

    }
```

**genericservice.cs**

```
public class GenericService<TEntity, TKey, Tdto> : IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, Tdto> where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    protected RunnerWriteDb<Tdto, TEntity> _runner; 

    protected readonly int PAGESIZE = 20;
    protected readonly TavoraContext _context;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _currentEntity;
    protected IMapper _mapper;

    public GenericService(TavoraContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _currentEntity = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

**IGeneric.cs**

```
public interface IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, Tdto>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IQueryable<DTO> GetAll<DTO>();

    //void Add(TEntity newItem);
    //void AddRange(List<TEntity> newItems);

    bool Update(TEntity updateItem);
    void UpdateRange(List<TEntity> updateItems);

    bool Delete(TKey id);
    bool DeleteRange(List<TEntity> removeItems);

    TEntity GetById(TKey id);

    RunnerWriteDbResult<TKey> Write(Tdto dto);
}
```

Comment: Use dependency injection to inject service into controller. Use tools like autofac to resolve dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that your `IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, Tdto>` is invariant. Meaning it's neither covariant nor contravariant in the `Tdto` generic type.

From the documentation:

> Covariance and contravariance are terms that refer to the ability to
>   use a more derived type (more specific) or a less derived type (less
>   specific) than originally specified. Generic type parameters support
>   covariance and contravariance to provide greater flexibility in
>   assigning and using generic types. When you are referring to a type
>   system, covariance, contravariance, and invariance have the following
>   definitions. The examples assume a base class named Base and a derived
>   class named Derived.
>
> Covariance
>
> Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.
>
> You can assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of
>   Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type IEnumerable.
>
> Contravariance
>
> Enables you to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally
>   specified.
>
> You can assign an instance of Action (Action(Of Base) in Visual
>   Basic) to a variable of type Action.
>
> Invariance
>
> Means that you can use only the type originally specified; so an
>   invariant generic type parameter is neither covariant nor
>   contravariant.
>
> You cannot assign an instance of List (List(Of Base) in Visual
>   Basic) to a variable of type List or vice versa.

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Since your `IGeneric` interface is invariant in all it's generic type parameter, the cast you're attempting (`IGeneric<Company, long, CompanySimpleDTO>` to `IGeneric<Company, long, CompanyDTO>`) is not allowed, since it can't guarantee that it's `Tdto` type parameter only goes into the interface.

So if you change your `IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, Tdto>` to this:

```
public interface IGeneric<TEntity, TKey, in Tdto> where TEntity: BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IQueryable<DTO> GetAll<DTO>();

    //void Add(TEntity newItem);
    //void AddRange(List<TEntity> newItems);

    bool Update(TEntity updateItem);
    void UpdateRange(List<TEntity> updateItems);

    bool Delete(TKey id);
    bool DeleteRange(List<TEntity> removeItems);

    TEntity GetById(TKey id);
}
```

It should work. Two things to note here though:

1. I assume `CompanyDTO` inherits from `CompanySimpleDTO`.
2. The generic type `Tdto` of the `IGeneric` interface is not used anywhere in the interface. If that's wrong and it's used in a way that it actually also needs to go out of the interface, then this solution will not work and I'm afraid you'll need to redesign it a bit.

Answer (score -2):

Use dependency injection to inject service into controller. Use pkgs like autofac to resolve dependency

Comment: who ever has given -1, can you please give reason for same?

Comment: I wasn't one of the people to give a -1, but I assume it is because this is not an answer that solves the OP's casting problem. I actually assume OP is already using some kind of dependency injection in his application. So while it's good advise to use DI, it won't help OP with his problem